# Jquery chaining error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I feel like i'm missing something super simple, but am banging my head against the wall. I have this function called "galleryImageSize", and also a parse of some JSON data. What I would like to have happen is after the data is parsed and the div is given a class of 'active' - run the "galleryImageSize" function to resize the image. I've chained the function call after the click event, but it gives me an error that the whole thing is not a function. Any ideas from the ether?

```
   function galleryImageSize () {
    var height = $("#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure img").data('height');
    var width = $("#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure img").data('width');
    var divHeight = $("#gallery-overlay .activeImage").height();
    var divWidth = $("#gallery-overlay .activeImage").width();
    var portraitRatio = height / width;
    var newWidth = divHeight / portraitRatio;
    var ratio = width / height;
    var newHeight = divWidth / ratio;

    if (height > width) {

        if (divHeight > height && divWidth > width) {
            $( "#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure img" ).width( width ).height( height );
        }

        if (divHeight > height && width > divWidth) {
            $( "#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure img" ).width( divWidth ).height( height * portraitRatio );
        }

        if (newWidth > divWidth) {
             $( "#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure img" ).width( divWidth ).height( newHeight );
        }

        else {
            $( "#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure img" ).width( newWidth ).height( divHeight );
        }
    }

    else {

        if (divWidth > width && divHeight > height) {
            $( "#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure img" ).width( width ).height( height );
        }

        else if (divWidth > width && height > divHeight) {
            $( "#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure img" ).width( width * ratio ).height( divHeight );
        }

        else if (newHeight > divHeight) {
            $( "#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure img" ).width( newWidth ).height( divHeight );
        }

        else {
            $( "#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure img" ).width( divWidth ).height( newHeight );
        }
    }

 }

$('.gallery-fire').each(function(e) {
    $(document).on('click', '.gallery-fire', function(event){
        var request = $(this).data('gallery');
        var title = $(this).data('title');
        $('#gallery-overlay .postTitle h1').html(title);
        $.getJSON(request, function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    $("#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure").html('<img data-height="'+data[i].height+'" data-width="'+data[i].width+'" src="'+data[i].image+'">');
                    $("#gallery-overlay .activeImage figcaption").html(data[i].caption+'<small>'+data[i].date+'</small>');                      
                }
            }
        });
        $( '#gallery-overlay' ).addClass( 'active');
    }).galleryImageSize (); 
});
```

Updated Code still doesn't work:

```
$('.gallery-fire').each(function(e) {
    $(document).on('click', '.gallery-fire', function(event){
        var request = $(this).data('gallery');
        var title = $(this).data('title');
        $('#gallery-overlay .postTitle h1').html(title);
        var get = function() {
            $.getJSON(request, function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        $("#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure").html('<img data-height="'+data[i].height+'" data-width="'+data[i].width+'" src="'+data[i].image+'">');
                        $("#gallery-overlay .activeImage figcaption").html(data[i].caption+'<small>'+data[i].date+'</small>');                      
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        $.when( get() ).done(function() {
            $('#gallery-overlay').addClass( 'active');
            galleryImageSize("#gallery-overlay .activeImage figure img");
        });
    });
});     

    function galleryImageSize (value) {
    var height = $(value).data('height');
    var width = $(value).data('width');
    var divHeight = $("#gallery-overlay .activeImage").height();
    var divWidth = $("#gallery-overlay .activeImage").width();
    var portraitRatio = height / width;
    var newWidth = divHeight / portraitRatio;
    var ratio = width / height;
    var newHeight = divWidth / ratio;

    if (height > width) {

        if (divHeight > height && divWidth > width) {
            $( value ).width( width ).height( height );
        }

        if (divHeight > height && width > divWidth) {
            $( value ).width( divWidth ).height( height * portraitRatio );
        }

        if (newWidth > divWidth) {
             $( value ).width( divWidth ).height( newHeight );
        }

        else {
            $( value ).width( newWidth ).height( divHeight );
        }
    }

    else {

        if (divWidth > width && divHeight > height) {
            $( value ).width( width ).height( height );
        }

        else if (divWidth > width && height > divHeight) {
            $( value ).width( width * ratio ).height( divHeight );
        }

        else if (newHeight > divHeight) {
            $( value ).width( newWidth ).height( divHeight );
        }

        else {
            $( value ).width( divWidth ).height( newHeight );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't just chain any old function on to jQuery

Comment: @JaromandaX ..... if that s not possible ,share how can he do that....  he must be looking for solution on SO

Comment: you have to realize that $('gallery-fire').each() function will trigger when it loads the js file, and nothing will happend, and the .on("click") function will never happend while it's still inside of it. Simple code of what yo got there: https://jsfiddle.net/a2kngq67/ so you can see it

Comment: Find the image and then set the widht height in chainging. $( "#gallery-overlay .activeImage .figure" ).find('img").width( divWidth ).height( newHeight );  and what is figure is it a class or id?

Comment: @JaromandaX I came here not to answer, i come to SO to learn...so as user i expect an answer not opinion...And don't take that personally..#sorry #noOffense

Comment: @Cheshire thanks, i had tied it to a 'each' statement because there are multiple instances of it on the page and it loads a new instance with an infinite scroll. is there a better way to handle that?

Comment: @JaromandaX I appreciate the nudge in the right direction, definitely here to learn. I updated code taking it out of the chain and making it a separate call inside a 'when' statement. But it still won't fire and resize the image. I know the function works because when tied to a window resize it'll resize the image automatically. Any help?